# How to deploy angular in maven project?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, gcloud

I try to add frontend (angular) in my backend project to deploy it on GCP.
When I try in local with: `mvn appengine:run` no problem, but when I want to deploy it with `mvn package appengine:deploy` I get this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cannot upload file [/Users/.../project/target/appengine-staging/**static**/front/node/node], which has size [41783856] (greater than maximum allowed size of [33554432]). Please delete the file or add to the skip_files entry in your application .yaml file and try again.

I didn't have a file: `app.yaml`.
I try to add `.gcloudignore` file but didn't work.
I don't know what I can do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [32MB static file limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Code) with App Engine and this corresponds to the error you're receiving.

Evidently, you're including a file `/Users/.../project/target/appengine-staging/static/front/node/node` (possibly a NodeJS binary?) in your upload to App Engine and this is being rejected.

You should only include your Java-related sources and the static content (HTML|JavaScript) that forms the Angular app.

If you're unable to streamline the directory that's being deployed, you can use [`.gcloudignore`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) to exclude content from the upload.